# Есть число в списке и нужно вывести соседние от него числа (слева и справа)

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть список из чисел, я нашел в нем число с максимальным значением и хочу вывести соседние от него числа. Одно слева и одно справа. Не знаю, как их обозначить.

```
def A(linst) :   
    v_max = max(linst)
    z = [x for x in enumerate(linst)]     
    for i in z :
        if v_max in i and                 # finish
```

Comment: а список замкнутый? т.е. если макс число 0 индекс, то слева его будет последнее число, тоже самое и для если макс число последнее в списке

Comment: Список примерно такой - [3, 6, -2, -6, 8, 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если макс число 0 индекс, то слева от него будет считаться последнее число списка, тоже самое и если макс число последнее в списке:

```py
def foo(numbers: list) -> tuple:
    max_num = max(numbers)

    index_max_num = numbers.index(max_num)

    left_index = index_max_num - 1
    # Индекс последнего элемента
    if left_index < 0:
        left_index = len(numbers) - 1

    right_index = index_max_num + 1
    # Индекс первого элемента
    if right_index >= len(numbers):
        right_index = 0

    return numbers[left_index], max_num, numbers[right_index]


print(foo([3, 6, -2, -6, 8, 3]))  # (-6, 8, 3)

print(foo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))  # (4, 5, 1)
print(foo([1, 3, 5, 9, 2]))  # (5, 9, 2)
print(foo([5, 3, 1, 4, 2]))  # (2, 5, 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Первое что пришло в голову:

```
def foo(array):
    if array[array.index(max(array))] == array[-1]: 
        return (array[array.index(max(array))-1], array[0])
    return (array[array.index(max(array))-1], array[array.index(max(array))+1])

print(foo([15, 11, 20])) # (11, 15)
print(foo([5, 4, 2])) # (2, 4)
print(foo([1, 5, 3])) # (1, 3)
```

Вообще это лямбдой можно сделать:

```
foo = lambda array: (array[array.index(max(array))-1], array[0]) if array[array.index(max(array))] == array[-1] else (array[array.index(max(array))-1], array[array.index(max(array))+1])
```

Answer (score 4):

Решение с использованием Numpy модуля:

```
import numpy as np

In [127]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [128]: ix_max = a.argmax()

In [129]: a[[(ix_max-1) % len(a), ix_max, (ix_max+1) % len(a)]]
Out[129]: array([4, 5, 1])
```

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы напечатать через пробел наибольший элемент и его соседей слева и справа в списке `L`:

```
i = max(range(len(L)), key=L.__getitem__)
index_left = i - 1
index_right = (i + 1) % len(L)
print(L[index_left], L[index_right])  # -> -6 3
```

Код предполагает, что список циклический:

- слева от первого элемента находится последний
- справа от последнего элемента находится первый

Также индекс `-1` интерпретируется как `len(L) - 1` (как обычно для стандартных последовательностей).

Answer (score 1):

```
def get(linst, prev_n=None):
    ilst, v_max = iter(linst), max(linst)
    for n in ilst:
        if n == v_max:
            try: next_n = next(ilst)
            except StopIteration: next_n = None
            return prev_n, n, next_n
        else: prev_n = n

print(get([1, 2, 9, 4, 5]))  # (2, 9, 4)
print(get([9, 2, 3, 4, 5]))  # (None, 9, 2)
print(get([1, 2, 3, 4, 9]))  # (4, 9, None)
```