# Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести сумму двух его соседей

Tags: python-3.x

Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести сумму двух его соседей. Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними, одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце этого списка. Например, если на вход подаётся список "1 3 5 6 10", то на выход ожидается список "13 6 9 15 7" (без кавычек). Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же. Вывод должен содержать одну строку с числами нового списка, разделёнными пробелом.

```
count=[]
nums=input()
row = list(map(int, nums.split()))
i=0
while i<=len(row):
    if len(row) == 1:
        print(row[0])
    if i == 0:
        count.append(row[-1] + row[1])
    if i == len(row):
        count.append(row[-2] + row[0])
    if 0<i<len(row):
        count.append(row[i-1] + row[i+1])
    i+=1
print(count)
```

Не могу понять, почему выдает ошибку о превышении границ. Есть тут подобный вопрос, но не могу разобраться с ответами.

Comment: Допустим, список длиной 10, допустимые индексы от 0 до 9, у вас же цикл будет от 0 до 10 включительно.

Comment: Вот это я затупил, жесть. Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой вариант решения:

```
def getSumElements(array):
    result = []
    if len(array) == 1:
        return array
    for index, elem in enumerate(array):
        if index == 0:
            result.append(sum([array[-1], array[1]]))
        elif index == len(array)-1:
            result.append(sum([array[-2], array[0]]))
        else:
            result.append(sum([array[index - 1], array[index + 1]]))
    return result
print(getSumElements([1, 2, 1, 3, 2])) # [4, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```

Чтобы Ваш код заработал, отнимите от каждого `len(row)` единицу.

Так как `len()` вернет кол-во элементов а не индексы, например:

```
In [32]: array = [1, 2, 3]

In [33]: len(array)
Out[33]: 3
```

как видим получили `3`, но индексы у нас: `0, 1, 2`.

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: работает неправильно, например для `array=[1, 2, 1, 3, 2]`, result == `[4, 4, 4, 3, 4]`, а должен `[4, 2, 5, 3, 4]`

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, спасибо, поправил

Comment: `sum([a, b])` можно записать как `a+b` здесь. Случай `index==0` у вас уже и так обрабатывается, нет необходимости в отдельную ветку выносить. Чтобы обработать, `i=len(L)-1`, [можно `(i+1) % len(L)` использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648633/23044), тогда все if можно убрать. Для заведомо маленького ввода, можно [упростить и не считать индексы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540482/23044)

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1, 3, 5, 6, 10]
ln = len(array)

# способ с индексами
if ln > 1:
    result = ' '.join(str(array[i-1] + array[i+1]) for i in range(ln-1)) \
             + ' %s' % (array[-2] + array[0])
else: result = str(array[0]) if array else ''
print(result)

# способ с итераторами
import itertools

def nums_by_iter():
    r = itertools.cycle(array)
    next(r)
    right = next(r)
    left = array[-1]
    for l in array:
        yield str(left + right)
        left, right = l, next(r)

if ln > 1:
    result = ' '.join(nums_by_iter())
else: result = next(iter(array), '')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

быстродействие

```
import random, itertools, timeit

def nums_by_iter():
    '''способ с итераторами'''
    if len(array) > 1:
        def get_summ():
            right = itertools.cycle(array)
            next(right); next(right)
            for left in array:
                yield left + next(right)
        *last, first = get_summ()
        return [first] + last
    return array

def nums_by_index():
    '''способ с индексами'''
    ln = len(array)
    if ln > 1:
        return [array[i-1]+array[i+1] for i in range(ln-1)] + [array[-2]+array[0]]
    else: return array

def getSumElements():
    '''вариант Alban'''
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = tuple(random.randrange(1000000) for _ in range(100))
    for func in [nums_by_iter, nums_by_index, getSumElements, ]:
        print('{t} сек - {n}'.format(t=round(timeit.Timer(func).timeit()), n=func.__name__))
```

out:

```
30 сек - nums_by_iter
33 сек - nums_by_index
94 сек - getSumElements
```